# Calculate the ideal bottom margin for headers

Tags: html, css, header, margin

I have headers and each have some margin.

I use http://pxtoem.com/ witch is based on the [Normalize CSS project](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

I looked on margins, and they are **not proportial** in my opinion.

### Question:

How to calculate the ideal bottom margin for headers?

*Note: Looking for some calculator / tool / formula*

### HTML:

```
<h1>Header H1</h1>
<h2>Header H2</h2>
<h3>Header H3</h3>
<h4>Header H4</h4>
<h5>Header H5</h5>
<h6>Header H6</h6>
```

### CSS:

```
/* Base: 1em = 14px */

body {
    font-size: 0.875em;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 0.875em;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 0.875em;
}

h1 {font-size: 2em; margin: 0.67em 0;}
h2 {font-size: 1.5em; margin: 0.83em 0;}
h3 {font-size: 1.17em; margin: 1em 0;}
h4 {font-size: 1em; margin: 1.33em 0;}
h5 {font-size: 0.83em; margin: 1.67em 0;}
h6 {font-size: 0.75em; margin: 2.33em 0;}
```

### Output:

[image: preview]

Notice margin between H5 and H6.

I am open to your suggestions :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at articles on vertical rhythm and baseline structure.

http://typecast.com/blog/4-simple-steps-to-vertical-rhythm

http://alistapart.com/article/settingtypeontheweb

You're on the right lines already but I'd start with setting the body font-size in pixels, with everything else (including line-height) relative to that using ems.

E.g:

```
body { 
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.6em; /* 24px */ }

p { padding-bottom: 1.6em;  /* 24px */  }

h1 { 
  font-size: 2em; /* 30px */
  line-height: 1.6em; /* 24px */
  margin: 0 0 0.8em; /* 24px */ }

h2 { 
  font-size: 1.6em; /* 24px */
  line-height: 1em; /* 24px */
  margin-bottom: 1em; /* 24px */ }
```

In my example above, the body line-height 1.6em equals 24px. Therefore your baseline is 24px. That means line-heights should always be a multiple of that, and margins should be that too.

My H1 and H2 examples result in 24px margins underneath and 48px and 24px line-heights respectively. Of course you can start with any font-size you like and use any multiples of the body font-size or line-height, as long as the vertical rhythm is kept.

The key in typographical layout is baseline consistency. Makes for pretty neat layouts!

Comment: I use layout also for mobile devices, there for I don't use PX in font-size as you did. Did font resize on mobile devices if I set it hard to some px ( e.g. font-size: 15px; ) or it will be as you set in body?

Comment: Not sure about fonts resizing on mobiles. All my websites are responsive and use that structure. Even if the fonts do resize, the fact that everything is relative to the body baseline means the vertical rhythm and consistency is kept.

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak I don't think designing for mobiles is a reason not to use px for font size. Using em is only a relative sizing structure and will generate a size in pixels anyway (a figure that should be the same accross all devices). Whether a device appears to then resize things/zoom in or out etc. after that is irrelevant.